# Pass VM argument for Database configuration -D for Junit test using Maven

Tags: maven, junit, sonarqube

While executing Junit test cases on Eclipse we are passing VM arguments for DB configuration by `-D`, but while uploading the same Junit test cases to Sonar by Maven it's not working as no VM argument is set.

I have tried to pass arguments by `MAVEN_OPTS` on `MVN.sh` but it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting your DB configuration on the command line with system properties, consider setting them with profiles.

Add something like this to your pom.xml:

```
<profiles>
  <profile>
    <id>sonar</id>
    <build>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.12.3</version>
          <configuration>
            <systemPropertyVariables>
              <db.user>foo</db.user>
              <db.password>bar</db.password>
            </systemPropertyVariables>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </build>
  </profile>
</profiles>
```

Documentation:

http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/system-properties.html